# Как сделать анимация выезжающую за пределы окна в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Пишу простую программу и мне потребовалась анимация. НО мне **не** нужна анимация внутри окна (это я могу сделать), **нужно чтобы выезжало за пределы окна**.

Comment: Выезжало что? Контролы не могут находиться вне окна, поэтому вам придется менять форму самого окна, либо использовать что-то из Popup

Comment: Что бы выезжало grid.

Comment: Ну как я написал выше — это невозможно, но вы можете сымитировать такое поведение, сделав окно прозрачным и изменяя видимую часть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете разместить контролы за пределами окна, но вы можете сымитировать такое поведение, сделав окно прозрачным (но вам придется самостоятельно реализовать кнопки для закрытия/сворачивания, изменение размеров окна, его перетаскивание и вообще внешний вид):

```
<Window ...
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="LightGray"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                             From="0" To="200" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое)