# Выдвигающиеся панели

Tags: c#, wpf

Как на WPF можно реализовать выдвигающиеся панели.

Скажем, в окне есть внизу кнопка, нажимая на эту кнопку выдвигается окно с какими-то дополнительными опциями.

Comment: За пределы основного окна? Или внутри него?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хотелось бы и такой и такой пример увидеть.

Comment: а играть с размерами панели ее видимостью не пытались?

Comment: За пределы окна только так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/859460/218063 Внутри окна тоже по такому же принципу, только там не нужны будут заморочки с прозрачным окном и прочим

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/popup-overview

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо. А не подскажите еще вот что: выезжание отдельного окна, да так, что бы при перемещении основного окна, параллельно перемещалось и окно, которое выехало. Так сказать, в копилку всех способов.

Comment: Ну такой же принцип, анимируем изменение размеров окна, при событии перемещения основного окна перемещаем второстепенное